# Why does systemd process stop as soon as it starts for foreman server process?

Tags: centos, services, ruby, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to export a simple Ruby app using foreman. Based on its [usage](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#SYSTEMD-EXPORT) for systemd, I appear to be doing things correctly.

However, when I start the target/service, I get status messages along the lines of this:

```
systemd[1]: Starting app-web-1.service...
systemd[1]: Started app-web-1.service.
systemd[1]: Service app-web-1.service is not needed anymore. Stopping.
systemd[1]: Stopping app-web-1.service...
systemd[1]: Stopped app-web-1.service.
```

The process begins, then ends. I have no idea why this is happening.

Granted, I am not an expert in systemd. This is my first time dealing with service scripts so I am not sure if there is something in the generated files that is causing this.

When exporting through foreman, a few target and service files are created. Thus, there are a few I have to deal with.

Here are the contents of app.target:

```
[Unit]
StopWhenUnneeded=true
Wants=app-web.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the contents of app-web-1.target:

```
[Unit]
StopWhenUnneeded=true
Wants=app-web-1.service
```

Finally, app-web-1.service:

```
[Unit]
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
User=deployer
WorkingDirectory=/home/deployer/app/releases/20141202043054
Environment=PORT=5000
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma -p 5000 '
Restart=always
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=%n
KillMode=process
```

Obviously, `StopWhenUnneeded` is part of the problem, but I am not sure what this is supposed to do in context of starting a web server within my app.

Can anyone help me figure how to get the server running and permanent?

Answer (score 2):

While grawity was a great help on figuring out what the problem was, I finally solved by running a simple, but overlooked command:

```
sudo systemctl enable app.target
```

That was it. Just enable the target and the service will work like a charm.

The [CoreOS docs](https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/) helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

As in the [manual pages](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StopWhenUnneeded=), `StopWhenUnneeded=true` means "stop this unit as soon as no other active units depend on it anymore".

For example, if you start `app.target`, it depends on `app-web-1.target` which will also be started, and likewise depends on `app-web-1.service`.

But if you *stop* the main `app.target` later, normally it wouldn't affect other two units at all – they don't have any dependencies in the "reverse" direction, so both `app-web-1.target` and `app-web-1.service` would continue running.

In other words, the most likely intention was to allow one to stop everything using just `systemctl stop app.target`, without having to stop each service manually. *It would have worked* if the setting was only in the "sub"-unit files (although it's not ideal – BindsTo= is better in this case).

So the problem is with `StopWhenUnneeded=` in the main app.target unit. Since you start it manually, it never has *any* other units depending on it, therefore it will be stopped immediately.